# translate C++ function in Android

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop an Android app that does the same as a function written in C++ to communicate between the mobile phone and a remote ethernet interface (I don't know what it exactly is…).

I know that I have to pass to the interface 15 bytes, retrieved from hex values, to pilot some loads connected to the interface.

I've tried a few things, the closest to the correct solution seems to be this one:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.100:1001");

        try {
            //String message "AA10A0F0F0FFFF0102FF00010091A5";              
            byte[] messaggioInBytes={(byte)10101010, //AA
                    (byte)00010000,  //10
                    (byte)10100000,  //A0
                    (byte)11110000,  //F0
                    (byte)11110000,  //F0
                    (byte)11111111,  //FF
                    (byte)11111111,  //FF
                    (byte)00000001,  //01
                    (byte)00000010,  //02
                    (byte)11111111,  //FF
                    (byte)00000000,  //00
                    (byte)00000001,  //01
                    (byte)00000000,  //00
                    (byte)10010001,  //91
                    (byte)10100101}; //A5

            httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(messaggioInBytes));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request

            httpclient.execute(httppost);


            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("ConnectionHandler", "Error", e);

            }
```

With this code the ethernet interface stops blinking and put itself to listening but it doesn't seem to receive the correct command string of bytes.

My doubts are connected to:
 1. the format of the command to send
 2. the type of connection to use

The only thing I know about the system is that it works well with this C++ function, so I would like to know if there is a way to translate it in Java code for Android instead of using Android NDK to import it.

The C++ function is the following:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::SendClick(TObject *Sender)
{
unsigned char Buffer[15];
AnsiString Line;
Buffer[0] = 0xAA;
...
Buffer[13] = 0x91;
Buffer[14] = 0xA5;
ClientSocket1->Socket->SendBuf(Buffer,15);
}
```

Is there anyone who can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have other issues but when you are trying to fill the array with bytes you are trying to get the byte value of the wrong numbers.

```
(byte) 00010000
```

is trying to stuff 10000 (ten thousand) into a byte.
Try putting in the hex values instead,

```
(byte)0xAA, (byte)0x10, etc.
```

Wrote a little test class just to verify that trying to cast a bit representation of a byte was the issue:

```
public class TestByteArray {

static byte[] myTestArray = {(byte) 0xAA,
                      (byte) 0x10,
                      (byte) 0xA0,
                      (byte) 0xF0,
                      (byte) 0xF0,
                      (byte) 0xFF,
                      (byte) 0xFF,
                      (byte) 0x01,
                      (byte) 0x02,
                      (byte) 0xFF,
                      (byte) 0x00,
                      (byte) 0x01,
                      (byte) 0x00,
                      (byte) 0x91,
                      (byte) 0xA5};

static byte[] myBitTestArray = {(byte)10101010, //AA
                         (byte)00010000,  //10
                         (byte)10100000,  //A0
                         (byte)11110000,  //F0
                         (byte)11110000,  //F0
                         (byte)11111111,  //FF
                         (byte)11111111,  //FF
                         (byte)00000001,  //01
                         (byte)00000010,  //02
                         (byte)11111111,  //FF
                         (byte)00000000,  //00
                         (byte)00000001,  //01
                         (byte)00000000,  //00
                         (byte)10010001,  //91
                         (byte)10100101}; //A5

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0;i < myTestArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(myTestArray[i] != myBitTestArray[i])
        {
            System.out.println("The value in myTestArray at index " + i + " is " + Integer.toHexString(myTestArray[i] & 0xFF).toUpperCase());
            System.out.println("The value in myBitTestArray at index " + i + " is " + Integer.toHexString(myBitTestArray[i] & 0xFF).toUpperCase());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Arrays are equal at index " + i);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: FWIW, the leading 0 causes "00010000" to be interpreted as an octal value -- it's actually 32768, not 10000.  Java behaves the same as C++.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure, thanks.  Either way the value 00010000 is different than 0x10.

Comment: thank you both for your comments. after some work i just solved the problem. i've tested that ClientSocket1->Socket->SendBuf(Buffer,15); is equivalent to a java socket and i could send bytes just like in c++ simply using outputstream. one of the last problem i had to figure was as harley wrote, the way to initialize the array of bytes: i thought it was possible to use bits but then, printing the values with valueOf(), i've seen the results were not the ones i were expecting to find. one thing i would like to know more is what happen in case of byte's overflow: (byte)(buf[0]+…+buf[n])>255